# Save Drawable ids and Strings in xml arrays

Tags: android, xml, sharedpreferences, android-sqlite, storage

I want to save some data like `drawable` ids and related `String` titles to my app to display in a `RecyclerView` with `custom_item_view`. What is the best way to do that?

- Resources (that's what I did .. about 30 arrays in arrays.xml file)
- SharedPreferences
- Database
- Internal Storage
- External Storage

**EDIT:**
The adviced approach will be used also to save about 60 `Map Markers` for 20 Locations.which means I will save additional 20 `array`
I hope someone help me.

Comment: Why did you want to store the data ? did they cam from an API ?

Comment: if you want to make it constants look into string-arrays

Comment: Thank you @Kassisdion No they didn't come from API, I collect the data from a website to make an App for it as training.

Comment: Thank you @RaviGadipudi It will be constants no changes will be made, I am already using `string-array`.
But I am Asking if this is the best way or there is better way to use.

Comment: For your purpose, string-array seems a good choice.